# Push a message and then Poll for a result

Tags: scala, gatling

We have two services, one which receives a message and a second which tells us when the message has been processed.  I'm trying to cover this in a gatling test.  Here's what I have so far but I'm struggling with the last bit..

```
scenario("push message and poll for result")
  .feed(feeder)
  .group("push and check: group") {
    exec(http("push")
      .put("/create")
      .check(status.is(200))
    )
      .asLongAs(session => !session.contains("messageProcessed")) {
        exec(http("poll")
          .get("/poll")
          .check(status.is(200), jsonPath("$.results[0].resultCount").saveAs("resultCount"))
      }

  }
```

My problem is resultCount will initially be zero so I want to keep polling until it becomes != 0.  When this happens I thought I could set "messageProcessed" to something and then it would drop out of the loop.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you look at the polling gatling dsl? http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.1/http/polling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the solution I used in the end

```
.asLongAs(session => getResultCount(session) == 0) {
```

and added this method:

```
def getResultCount(session: Session): Int = {
    session("resultCount").asOption[String].map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0)
  }
```